# Filter from comma sep. list in django model "whole word"

Tags: django, django-models

Can anyone help with this, I have a model like this:

```
class Searchpage(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

the "keywords" is a comma sep. list ex. "foo, foobar, foo bar"

Now I want to make a filter that match the words ...

```
Searchpage.objects.filter(keywords__contains="foo")
```

match correct

```
Searchpage.objects.filter(keywords__contains="bar")
```

match, but not correct... only whole word ..

I hope it makes sense ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use an extra model and a M2M relationship for the keywords to filter on. There are also dedicated packages for this like [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit).

But you could also use a regex filter:

```
Searchpage.objects.filter(keyword__regex=r'\bbar\b')
```

(haven't tested this, but I think it should work)